# 2 out of 3 of the columns in my index are being used. Why isn't the third?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have an index like

```
CREATE INDEX TS.INDEX_FACET_NAME ON TS.FACET
  (NAME ASC, ARCHIVED ASC, CATALOG_ID ASC);
```

and a large view who has a join like

```
left outer join (
  select concept_id, value as short_name, catalog_id 
    from ts.facet where name = 'shortName' and archived = 'N'
) f on f.concept_id = c.concept_id and f.catalog_id = cc.catalog_id
```

where c and cc are defined elsewhere.

In the explain plan

```
access("NAME"(+)='listItemName' AND "ARCHIVED"(+)='N')
filter("CATALOG_ID"(+) IS NOT NULL)
```

Why can't it use the catalog_id part of the index? I tried adding catalog_id is not null to the where clause to make it explicit but it still won't use the last column. In addition, for a join like

```
left outer join (
  select concept_id, value as data_type 
    from ts.facet where name = 'dataType' and archived = 'N'
) f on f.concept_id = c.concept_id
```

Why isn't the index being used if the subquery returns about 5% of the table? From the explain plan

```
filter("NAME"(+)='dataType' AND "ARCHIVED"(+)='N')
```

Comment: What's the operator related to the explain plan you show? In other words, the access and filter predicates qualify what?

Comment: Do you mean in the context of Oracle in general?

Comment: Do you need to do this is a subquery? Why not add the two where conditions to the "on" clause and join to the table directly? Sorry if this doesn't work in Oracle as I'm a sqlserver guy! I suspect that might help.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't it use the catalog_id part of the index?

The optimizer uses the index to service your inline query:

```
( select concept_id, value as short_name, catalog_id 
  from ts.facet where name = 'shortName' and archived = 'N' )
```

This subquery does not reference `catalog_id` so there is nothing the database can do with that column in the access path. However, it looks like it does use that column to further restrict the subquery's result set:

```
filter("CATALOG_ID"(+) IS NOT NULL)
```

This is because you *"tried adding catalog_id is not null to the where clause to make it explicit"* . As your follow-up question does show that the optimizer **is** using the indexed `catalog_id`, just not in the way you expected.

> Why isn't the index being used if the subquery returns about 5% of the table?

Probably because it's more efficient not to do that. By removing the join condition on `catalog_id` you have enlarged the potential result from the subquery, so the optimizer reckons it's better to select all the records from `facet` and discard the records it doesn't need.

The most common misunderstanding of database tuning is the idea that indexed reads are always faster. Actually a table scan is usually more performative than an indexed read unless the query selects a very small subset of records (like 1-2%). A single multi-block read can scoop up a large number of records; indexed reads are usually two i/o operations (read the index, read the table). This is a simplification - the optimizer is ridiculously smart these days, and it can call on a large arsenal of strategies to handle different scenarios.

---

> Well that filter on catalog_id was happening even before I added it to the where clause

There's a limit to what we can say for certain based on a snippet of the Explain Plan and a snippet of the query. So it's all just guessing here.

> Are you saying that the optimizer is actually using index for catalog_id? I would assume that it would be in the access() if it was.

So the optimizer is choosing to use the index to **select** on `name = 'shortName' and archived = 'N'` but only when you involve `catalog_id` in the join. So I'm guessing it is also using the index to **filter** on `catalog_id is not null`. However, the snippet you posted doesn't include the `id` or the `operation` so I can't be certain that both actions apply to the same step in the plan.

Now, when you remove the join on `catalog_id` then it doesn't use the index. I would hazard a guess that this is because the number of records where `catalog_id is not null` is quite small. But again, I don't know your data model, I can't see data volumes or skew.

Comment: Well that filter on catalog_id was happening even before I added it to the where clause. I added it to the where clause to see if I could help the index use it.

Are you saying that the optimizer is actually using index for catalog_id? I would assume that it would be in the access() if it was.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess because I don't have your test case or an 11g instance, but one possibility is that the optimizer is not able to merge the view because that would produce something like the following internally:

```
select ...
from   some_table cc
     , some_other_table c
     , facet f
where  f.name(+) = 'shortName'
and    f.archived(+) = 'N'
and    f.concept_id(+) = c.concept_id
and    f.catalog_id(+) = cc.catalog_id;
```

which is not valid because a table may be outer joined to at most one other table (ORA-01417).

See the comments on 'Outer Join View Merging' in
https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-view-merging-part-1:

> If a view is involved in an outer join with tables from the outer query block or if the view contains outer-joined tables, there are many additional restrictions on whether it is valid to merge the view. After view merging, it must be possible to express the query in terms of Oracle outer join syntax. This imposes one significant restriction on views on the left of an outer join: each table from the outer query block can be outer-joined to at most one underlying table of the view.

With a more detailed test case it would be interesting to see if this is still true in 12.1 where [the restriction is removed](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9537288000346639582).